# jQuery: Append Not Working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert a `ul` element inside of a 3<sup>rd</sup> `li` element inside of another `ul` element using `.append()`, but my code doesn't seem to do anything.

#### jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul.tier1 li:nth-child(3)').append('<ul class="tier2">{% for product_vendor in collection.all_vendors %}<li>{{ product_vendor | link_to_vendor }}</li>{% endfor %}');
});
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="mainnav">
  <ul class="tier1">
    <li id="blog">blog</li>
    <li class="">
      <a class="tier1title" href="/collections/newarrivals">New Arrivals</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/#">Brands</a>
      <li class="">
        <a class="tier1title" href="/#">Categories</a>
        <ul class="tier2">
          <li class="">
            <a href="/collections/knits">Knits</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="/collections/tops">Tops</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="/collections/dresses">Dresses</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="/collections/bottoms">Bottoms</a>
          </li>
            ...
          <li class="">
            <a class="tier1title" href="/collections/sale">Sale</a>
          </li>
          <li class="registerform">
            ...
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Open console, there are errors..

Comment: What are you trying to append? a template? that won't work (if you didn't override `append()`)…

Comment: @dfsq I don't see any errors in my console...

Comment: @nietonfir Trying to append Shopify liquid code

Comment: @nietonfir It doesn't work even if I delete the liquid code part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your third `<li>` tag is not actually closed :)

```
<li> <a href="/#">Brands</a>
```

Close it, and you'll be fine.

Edit:

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/oboh82vw/4/